Interop Word AddPicture not adding after a few already in
I am creating a Word file with a table and several rows, in some of which I add text and images.
Now, the problem I am facing is that after some images, the AddPicture method returns a null InlineShape. If I run the process 100 times, it always stops adding at the same point.
I modified the code so that it starts the word file from where it stops adding images and I add the missing ones correctly.
The process runs on .net 8 and is a console app.
Is it a memory problem? Interop?
Code:
foreach (var img in item.Images)
{
  if (File.Exists(img.Path))
  {
    tb.Rows.Add(Missing.Value);
    actualRow = GetLastRowCount(tb);
    tb.Cell(actualRow, 1).Split(1, 2);
    tb.Cell(actualRow, 1).PreferredWidthType = WdPreferredWidthType.wdPreferredWidthPercent;
    tb.Cell(actualRow, 1).SetWidth(150, WdRulerStyle.wdAdjustFirstColumn);

    tb.Rows[actualRow].Range.Borders[WdBorderType.wdBorderTop].LineStyle = WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleNone;
    
    PopulateCellEmpty(tb, actualRow, 1, false);

    try
    {
        object oMissing = Missing.Value;
        var autoScaledInlineShape = WordDocument.InlineShapes.AddPicture(img.Path, ref oMissing, true, tb.Cell(actualRow, 2).Range);
        if(autoScaledInlineShape != null)
        {
            var cmsToPoints = WordApplication.CentimetersToPoints(17);
            if (autoScaledInlineShape.Width > cmsToPoints)
                autoScaledInlineShape.Width = cmsToPoints;
        }
        else
        {
            PopulateCell(tb, actualRow, 2, img.Name, false, false, false, WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphLeft, WdCellVerticalAlignment.wdCellAlignVerticalTop);

            LogSeriLogInformation($"GenerateTopicSection - autoScaledInlineShape es nullo - " +
            $"Reporte: '{report.Id}', Seccion: '{title}', Imagen y path: '{img.Name}' y '{img.Path}', Fila: '{actualRow}', Columna: '{2}'");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        LogSeriLogInformation($"GenerateTopicSection - Exception - Al agregar imagen al archivo y modificar su tamaño. " +
            $"Reporte: '{report.Id}', Seccion: '{title}', Imagen y path: '{img.Name}' y '{img.Path}', Fila: '{actualRow}', Columna: '{2}'");
        throw;
    }

    tb.Rows.Add();
    actualRow = GetLastRowCount(tb);
    tb.Cell(actualRow, 1).Split(1, 2);
    tb.Cell(actualRow, 1).PreferredWidthType = WdPreferredWidthType.wdPreferredWidthPercent;
    tb.Cell(actualRow, 1).SetWidth(150, WdRulerStyle.wdAdjustFirstColumn);
    tb.Rows[actualRow].Range.Borders[WdBorderType.wdBorderTop].LineStyle = WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleNone;
    tb.Rows[actualRow].SetHeight(WordApplication.CentimetersToPoints((float)0.1), WdRowHeightRule.wdRowHeightExactly);
    PopulateCellEmpty(tb, actualRow, 1, false);
}

}
